# ConnectionRefusedError when connecting to test.mosquitto.org

Tags: python, windows, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I'm completely new to this protocol, python and paho-mqtt.
I want the simplest way for two publishers to publish to a topic. I also want a subscriber to listen to these messages. Previously, I don't know if it was because of a change I made in Python, but when I run the subscriber and then the first publisher, there is no problem. However, when I run the second one, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\MQTT\DigitalTwin2.py", line 14, in <module>
    dt_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "C:\...\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1044, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "C:\...\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_address=source)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\...\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

The Python codes are as follows: (The codes for the publishers are the same, only the client names are different)

Publisher #1&2:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from random import uniform
import time

def on_dt_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to Digital Twin-1 with result code 0")
    else:
        print("Connection to Digital Twin-1 failed with result code " + str(rc))

dt_client = mqtt.Client("Digital Twin-1")
dt_client.on_connect = on_dt_connect

dt_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)

while True:
    randNumber = uniform(3.0, 4.0)
    randNumber = round(randNumber, 4)
    dt_client.publish("topic", "Digital Twin-1: " + str(randNumber))
    print("..." + str(randNumber) + "...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Subscriber:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_sd_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to Smart Device with result code 0")
    else:
        print("Connection to Smart Device failed with result code " + str(rc))

def on_sd_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("...", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

device_client = mqtt.Client("Smart Device")
device_client.on_connect = on_sd_connect

device_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)

device_client.loop_start()
device_client.subscribe("topic")
device_client.on_message = on_sd_message

time.sleep(30)

device_client.loop_stop()
```

I've looked through previous questions, but no one seems to be trying to connect three clients. Additionally, the things I did before were:

- I added a new rule with New Rule from Windows Defender.
- While using MQTT Explorer, I added a password. When I couldn't connect with the password, I closed MQTT Explorer. I deleted the password file I created from the mosquitto folder.

I tried to follow these steps by watching YouTube videos.

Comment: The `ConnectionRefusedError` means that a network connection can't be to the target host & port. In this case you're attempting to connect to `test.mosquitto.org:1883`. You should ensure there is a server process listening for connections on this host & port and that it is reachable across the network from your client (e.g. no firewall is blocking it).

Comment: BTW, it is common to have _thousands_ of MQTT clients so 3 (i.e. 2 publishers & 1 subscriber) should really be no problem.

Comment: @JustinBertram First, thanks for your answers. I know 3 clients are no problem but before I made some changes, they were working. After the changes, first I got ConnectionRefusedError. Then I changed something in Python and I got socket.timeout: timed out error. When I revert the changes, I got this same error again.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided the problem doesn't appear to be with the code. It appears to be somewhere on the network (e.g. the MQTT broker isn't actually listening on `test.mosquitto.org:1883`, the connection is being blocked, etc.). Have you done any investigation on this aspect? If so, what did you find?

Comment: @JustinBertram `test.mosquitto.org` is demo broker run by the developer of the mosquitto broker. While it comes with absolutely no SLA it is normally running, but users have no access to that machine or it's logs. I've just tested it with the mosquitto cmd line tools and it is up and running normally.

Comment: @hardillb Yes, I forgot to mention that. Thanks.

Comment: @JustinBertram I've researched, but everything I'm working on is new to me. So, when I find things during my research, I either don't fully understand them or try to do everything I see in the YouTube videos I watch. Honestly, I'm in a bit of a panic because I'm in a hurry.

Comment: If the MQTT broker is up and running then something must be blocking network access from your client. At this point I don't see any other reason why you'd be getting a `ConnectionRefusedError` from Python's socket library. Most of your code is completely irrelevant because the problem is happening on `connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)` which is one of the first things executed. If your code isn't the problem and the broker isn't the problem then it must be something in between.

Comment: @JustinBertram The problem is the while loop. When I remove the loop and just ask them to send a single message, all three can work, and the subscriber can receive and print both messages. Do you know why the loop is causing an issue?

Comment: According to the stack-trace you provided in your question execution isn't even making it to the `while` loop in the publisher. It's failing before that at `connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)`. At this point I can't explain what you're seeing given the information you've provided. For what it's worth, I copied and pasted your code with no modifications and I can run multiple instances of it on my local machine with no problems. So that proves the code is not the problem. It's something in your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your publisher and subscriber code **exactly** with no modifications:

`publisher1.py`:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from random import uniform
import time

def on_dt_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to Digital Twin-1 with result code 0")
    else:
        print("Connection to Digital Twin-1 failed with result code " + str(rc))

dt_client = mqtt.Client("Digital Twin-1")
dt_client.on_connect = on_dt_connect

dt_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)

while True:
    randNumber = uniform(3.0, 4.0)
    randNumber = round(randNumber, 4)
    dt_client.publish("topic", "Digital Twin-1: " + str(randNumber))
    print("..." + str(randNumber) + "...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

`subscriber.py`:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_sd_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to Smart Device with result code 0")
    else:
        print("Connection to Smart Device failed with result code " + str(rc))

def on_sd_message(client, userdata, message):
    print("...", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

device_client = mqtt.Client("Smart Device")
device_client.on_connect = on_sd_connect

device_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)

device_client.loop_start()
device_client.subscribe("topic")
device_client.on_message = on_sd_message

time.sleep(30)

device_client.loop_stop()
```

I can run both of them on my local machine with no problems.

If I copy the publisher code and change the client ID (e.g. change `Digital Twin-1` to be `Digital Twin-2`) then I can run 2 publishers concurrently and 1 subscriber. Again, everything works fine.

Therefore, your code is not the problem.

I believe it's something in your environment preventing network access to `test.mosquitto.org:1883` or possibly a problem with `test.moquitto.org` itself. For what it's worth, the [website for `test.mosquitto.org`](https://test.mosquitto.org/) lists these caveats (emphasis mine):

> This server is provided as a service for the community to do testing, but it is also extremely useful for testing the server. This means that it will often be running unreleased or experimental code and **may not be as stable as you might hope**. It may also be slow - the broker often runs under valgrind or perf. Finally, not all of the features may be available all of the time, depending on what testing is being done. In particular, websockets and TLS support are the most likely to be unavailable.
>
> **In general** you can expect the server to be up and to be stable though.

Comment: The issue was with 'test.mosquitto.org.' I can't believe it. I didn't listen to you from the beginning because it's official. But yes, you were right. I apologize for taking up so much of your time. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your publisher code should also be updated to either start the client loop or call it in the while loop

Either:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from random import uniform
import time

def on_dt_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to Digital Twin-1 with result code 0")
    else:
        print("Connection to Digital Twin-1 failed with result code " + str(rc))

dt_client = mqtt.Client("Digital Twin-1")
dt_client.on_connect = on_dt_connect

dt_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)

while True:
    randNumber = uniform(3.0, 4.0)
    randNumber = round(randNumber, 4)
    dt_client.publish("topic", "Digital Twin-1: " + str(randNumber))
    print("..." + str(randNumber) + "...")
    dt_client.loop()
    time.sleep(1)
```

or

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from random import uniform
import time

def on_dt_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to Digital Twin-1 with result code 0")
    else:
        print("Connection to Digital Twin-1 failed with result code " + str(rc))

dt_client = mqtt.Client("Digital Twin-1")
dt_client.on_connect = on_dt_connect

dt_client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)
dt_client.loop_start()

while True:
    randNumber = uniform(3.0, 4.0)
    randNumber = round(randNumber, 4)
    dt_client.publish("topic", "Digital Twin-1: " + str(randNumber))
    print("..." + str(randNumber) + "...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is because if the payload is ever bigger than the network MTU it will require the loop to send the mulitple packets required or if you move to use QOS greater than zero the loop is needed to handle the extra handshake packets for each publish.

The loop is also needed to handled any callbacks (including the `on_connect`)